# Does weather effect prayer time?

Tags: salat, prayer-timings

Assalamualaikum waramatullahi wabarakatuhu,

My question is, in my society we use to pray magrib by 10 minutes to 7 o'clock or sometimes 7 o'clock, but today is like we are going to have rain and the day is already dark by 6 o'clock 30 minutes, so are we going to pray magrib at that time or wait till our regular time.

Comment: Whether has no influence on the prayer time however might be a reason for the permission to join some prayers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Prayer times are traditionally calculated according to the position of the sun, regardless of the weather.

There is typically a 90 minute window (varies by season and location) for praying maghrib for it to be valid, so even though it's typically prayed at the beginning of that period it is permissible to delay it if you are unable to determine the position of the sun and need to ensure you're not praying it outside of its time. However, praying it early because of inclement weather is a mistake no matter how dark it is.